# A very simple question about integrated jinja2 to pylons

Tags: integration, pylons, jinja2

I'm integrating jinja2 to pylons, I see in the [document page](http://jinja.pocoo.org/2/documentation/integration) there is:

```
from jinja2 import Environment, PackageLoader
config['pylons.app_globals'].jinja_env = Environment(
    loader=PackageLoader('yourapplication', 'templates')
)
```

My question is: what should I use for `yourapplication`? Suppose my application is 'test', what should I write as `yourapplication`?

Comment: After reading the doc of PackageLoader, I know it's just the parent directory of `templates` dir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if would guess that you should use 'test' as well, like this:

```
config['pylons.app_globals'].jinja_env = Environment(
    loader=PackageLoader('test', 'templates')
)
```

in general 'yourapplication' should match the name of your main applicaton package i.e. the one that contains 'config', 'controllers', 'lib' and so on)

*hint:* if you start on a fresh project you will be prompted for the template engine during setup, so just enter `jinja2` to replace mako as default templating language and everything will be configured automatically

```
paster create -t pylons myapp
...
Enter template_engine (mako/genshi/jinja2/etc: Template language) ['mako']:
```